# Blazor on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2) does not work. Any Ideas what to do next?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, blazor, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried hosting Blazor on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2).

But calling the URI from my browser, I get the following text (which is the standard index page meaning to disappear when the app is loaded):

"Loading...
An unhandled error has occurred. Reload "

Clearly, it didn't manage to load the Blazor App.

**Any ideas what I can do next to find the error?** For testing purpose I tested this with a blank project, so there is no own code of myself that may cause the problem!

It's a ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor Webassembly Solution (the one with three Projects: .Server, .Client, .Shared). A Blazor-Server-App works, so there is no general problem with the Server, NET Core or Blazor.

Thanks!
Tim

Comment: For WebAssembly based projects, the type of browser you use matters a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work with the current versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera nor Edge.

Comment: Then you might use tools like Fiddler to see if any download fails. But since you don't have a successful case to compare with, I think it is not easy for you to discover the cause.

Comment: Maybe you need to add MIME types for .wasm files and for .DLL files?